Where to put Trigger class h2 embedded mode?
I created a trigger class com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.triggers.MyTrigger extends org.h2.api.Trigger using the Sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(NAME CHARACTER VARYING(255))

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS MY_TRIGGER
ON TEST BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW
CALL 'com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.triggers.MyTrigger'

running this code in vscode (maven project) with h2 as a dependency outputs ```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Error creating or initializing trigger "MY_TRIGGER" object, class "com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.triggers.MyTrigger", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Class ""com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.triggers.MyTrigger"" not found [90086-224]"; see root cause for details; SQL statement:
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS "PUBLIC"."MY_TRIGGER"
BEFORE INSERT 
ON "PUBLIC"."TEST"
FOR EACH ROW
CALL "com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.triggers.MyTrigger" [90043-232]
        at com.h2database@2.3.232/org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:644)
        at com.h2database@2.3.232/org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.readSQLException(SessionRemote.java:663)
        at com.h2database@2.3.232/org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.readException(SessionRemote.java:646)
        at com.h2database@2.3.232/org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:620)
        at com.h2database@2.3.232/org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:225)
        at com.h2database@2.3.232/org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:262)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.lambda$6(DatabaseController.java:117)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.lambda$2(DatabaseController.java:81)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.execute(DatabaseController.java:65)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.execute(DatabaseController.java:78)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.execute(DatabaseController.java:76)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.execute(DatabaseController.java:75)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.data.DatabaseController.execute(DatabaseController.java:117)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.Main.test(Main.java:49)
        at com.gamebad.storagemanager/com.gamebad.storagemanager.Main.main(Main.java:172)

but packaging the project as a single jar with all the dependencies included and running it work (it finds the MyTrigger class and executes it
My guess would be that while running throught vscode with h2 as an external dependency caused it to run with a different classpath than my application resulting in it not finding my code.
How to specify the classpath for a mavem dependency or at least know or print it some how.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I figured it out.
Turns out I was running h2-console which has it's own jar somewhere else with it's own classpath and I was connecting the database I want from h2-console in AUTO_SERVER=TRUE so when running from vscode it connected to h2-console and tried to look for MyTrigger in there, So I closed h2-console and tried and it works from the IDE now.
Still isn't there a workaround to keep h2-console open while running ?
